# How to delete the numbers on x and y axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I have a webpage that needs a simple single-line straight chart that looks like this:
[image: graph]
<sub>(source: [asamcontinuum.org](https://asamcontinuum.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/P105_ASAM-Continuum-of-Care_700pxwide.jpg))</sub>

I tried using different graphs but somehow this is the best one I could come up with. It really is a simple graph with nothing much to show

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Weight'],
    [0, 0],
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [2.1, 2.1],
    [2.5, 2.5],
    [3, 3],
    [3.1, 3.1],
    [3.3, 3.3],
    [3.5, 3.5],
    [3.7, 3.7],
    [4, 4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Age',
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 15
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Weight',
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 15
    },
    legend: 'none',
    trendlines: {
      "0": {}
    }
    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

How can I remove the x and y axis numbers and just put them up on one single line just like the graph?
Also, is it possible to remove the tooltips that appear on the graph and make the graph horizontal?

Comment: For some reason, the chart didn't load. Got error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Dude, you've got some 15 errors in the script. Try getting the right one.

Comment: The script is all fine. I even tried running the code snippet button and the graph shows up. @PraveenKumarPurushothaman

Comment: Er... I hope you understand that I totally redid the code - took me about 10 mins to make it work. Try running your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53916674/1)?